# Interdigital filter ground connection on PCB

Tags: pcb-design, rf, filter, microwave, microstrip

I have used an online designer utility for my 5 GHz to 6 GHz RF output filter, on the schematic it generated it had shown ground attach points, but I am not sure if I designed ground connections and the filter surroundings correctly.

Is the filter connected to ground correctly?

[image: board design with the filter]

Red is top layer, blue is the bottom ground plane layer underneath. There are two layer which I skipped for visibility: an another ground plane layer under the filter (0.2 mm of dielectric, this height I used for calculations) and a VCC layer sandwiched between these two ground planes.

[image: calculated filter schematic]

Example filter from a manufactured device:

[image: example filter]